# Как результаты двух запросов MySQl объединить в одной таблице

Tags: mysql

Есть два запроса к двум таблицам `plan`и `fact`, отличающимся только одним полем ***plan*** и ***fact***! Выборка делается по общему полю ***manager_ref***.
Как результаты запросов  объединить в одну таблицу!
UNION не работает из-за разного количества строк в результатах выборок.

```
SELECT u1.description as manager, 
u.description as partner, 
g.description as group_description, 
fa.description as functional_attribute_description, 
p.date, 
p.currency AS plan_currency,
p.proceeds AS plan
FROM `remote_test`.`plan` p 
LEFT JOIN groups g ON p.nomenclature_ref = g.ref 
LEFT JOIN functional_attribute fa ON p.functional_attribute_ref = fa.ref
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.partner_ref = u.ref
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON p.manager_ref = u1.ref
WHERE p.manager_ref = 'ad7f5691-def9-4009-af54-1a91eada00ad'
AND p.date = '2021-05-01'
ORDER BY fa.description
```

Второй запрос

```
SELECT u1.description as manager, 
u.description as partner, 
g.description as group_description, 
fa.description as functional_attribute_description, 
f.date, 
f.currency AS fact_currency,
f.proceeds AS fact
FROM `remote_test`.`fact` f 
LEFT JOIN groups g ON f.nomenclature_ref = g.ref 
LEFT JOIN functional_attribute fa ON f.functional_attribute_ref = fa.ref
LEFT JOIN users u ON f.partner_ref = u.ref
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON f.manager_ref = u1.ref
WHERE f.manager_ref = 'ad7f5691-def9-4009-af54-1a91eada00ad'
AND f.date = '2021-05-01'
ORDER BY fa.description
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что значит "Объединить", что бы друг под другом оказались или как ? А то ведь UNION как раз нормально должен их объединять, ему все равно сколько строк в выборке, главное что бы количество колонок совпадало, а оно совпадает

Comment: В результате хочется получить рядом стоящие две колонки `plan` и `fact`. Дело в том что в `fact` количество строк будет намного меньше чем `plan` и я не могу понять есть ли инструмент который мне позволит лишь только кодом в запросе, без фильтрации результатов в Exel получить результирующую таблицу!

Comment: Покажите пример, что вы хотите получить. "рядом" можно понимать очень по разному.

Comment: Я кстати не понял почему у вас выходит разное количество записей. У вас все условия в запросах полностью совпадают, значит и строки будут на выходе те же самые. А что там в колонках дело десятое. И если вдруг надо что бы что то было рядом, надо соединять это join а для этого должен быть точный критерий что "рядом" с чем должно оказаться

Comment: @Mike У него базовые таблицы разные.

Comment: *UNION не работает из-за разного количества строк в результатах выборок.* Не может быть. UNION-у похрен на количество строк, ему лишь бы структуры совпадали.

Comment: Подозреваю, что человек все же хочет сделать join а не union. Отсюда и про разное количество строк, и про `хочется получить рядом стоящие две колонки` из разных запросов, и про фильтрацию в excel (наверно речь о inner join). Но это все домыслы, нужно вопрос уточнять и добавить пример ответа.

Comment: Сейчас попытаюсь визуально показать картинкой!

Comment: Добавил картинку! В итоге хочется получить две колонки `plan` и `fact` рядом! Где факта нет там пусто!!! Простите если слишком заморочливо объясняю, стараюсь как можно проще!

Comment: Ну так это ROW_NUMBER() OVER (..) и потом NATURAL JOIN.

Comment: Это все можно в одном запросе сделать?